# Detect Camera Disconnect

Tags: c#, c++

In our company we are using a camera that has a RGB connection and we use a USB digitizer to connect it to the computer. What are various means to detect that the camera is disconnected?

Currently we know that if the USB device (digitizer) is disconnected, we get a device disconnected notification (hooking onto windows events). The problem is when we remove the RGB connection, we are finding it to detect the disconnection means. So we are doing some frame analysis like if all the pixels have the same RGB value, that means its a black image and that means something wrong.

Since camera is a integral solution (medical device), detecting camera disconnect is related to patient safety. Is there a better way to find.

Would really appreciate your input.

Comment: So when you disconnect the RGB (I'm assuming a component type connection) from the USB digitizer, this disconnect is being registered as a 'USB disconnect notification' as well as the actual digitizer USB disconnect?? (just clarifying)

Comment: There is a tool called: WBEMTest.exe which may help you find the RGB info in the WMI database.

Comment: No we do not get a device disconnected if the rgb cable is removed.

Comment: Hi Steve, Thanks for pointing me to WBEMTest. Could not get any information online in connection to RGB. Do you have more details? Thanks.

Comment: I have no further information.